# Conservation of Angular Momentum in Elliptical Orbit: simple yet confusing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

**Problem**

> A satellite orbit is to change from elliptical to circular with radius $2 R$. The satellite is at point $A$ on the elliptical orbit as shown in the figure. Determine the speed of the satellite in $A$ so that its elliptical path is tangent to the circular path of radius $2 R$ in $B$. Further, determine the necessary change in the satellite's velocity in $B$ for it to enter the circular orbit. Must the satellite's speed be increased or decreased in $B$ to enable the transition?

[image]

**Solution**

> 1. First consider the elliptic path with points $A$ and $B$. The angular momentum of the satellite is conserved during the motion, which gives
>    $$
>    C A v_A=O B v_B \Rightarrow 4 R v_A=2 R v_B \Rightarrow v_B=2 v_A
>    $$
>    The energy equation gives:
>    $$
>    T_A+V_A=T_B+V_B \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} m v_A^2-m g \frac{R^2}{O A}=\frac{1}{2} m v_B^2-m g \frac {R^2}{O B} \Rightarrow v_B^2-v_A^2=2 g R^2\left(\frac{1}{2 R}-\frac{1}{5 R}\right)=\frac{3}{5} g R
>    $$
>    The last equations result in
>    $$
>    3 v_A^2=\frac{3}{5} g R \Rightarrow v_A=\sqrt{\frac{g R}{5}} \text { och } v_B=2 \sqrt{\frac{g R}{5}}
>    $$
> 2. Let us now determine the speed of the satellite $v_{B,\text { circ }}$ on the circular path with radius $2 R$. The normal component of the force equation gives
>    $$
>    \mathbf{e}_n: \quad m \frac{v_{B, \text{circ}}^2}{2 R}=G \frac{m M}{4 R^2} \Rightarrow v_{B, \text{circ}}^2 =\frac{G M}{2 R}=\frac{g R^2}{2 R}=\frac{g R}{2} \Rightarrow v_{B, \text{circ}}=\sqrt{\frac{g R }{2}}
>    $$
> 3. Determine the required speed change. We note that
>    $$
>    v_{B, \text { circ }}=\sqrt{\frac{g R}{2}}<v_B=\sqrt{\frac{4 g R}{5}} \Rightarrow \Delta v=v_B-v_ {B, \text { circ }}=\underline{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sqrt{g R} \approx 0.19 \sqrt{g R}}
>    $$

**Question**

I've seem to have run into a conceptual issue regarding the conservation of angular momentum. The exercise seemingly uses the center of the ellipse, $C$ (I assume the center given the figure), instead of the foci $O$, when using the conservation of angular momentum.

I don't understand how this holds, in other words how
$$
C A v_A=O B v_B.
$$

In my mind it should be
$$
O A v_A=O B v_B,
$$

given that $O$ is the foci of both the elliptical and circular orbits. The angular momentum is conserved given that the net force acting on the particle is parallel to the radial direction. This surely is not true for the center $C$ of the elliptical orbit.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the two points v is perpendicular to CA or OB, but you can also have $\{|\vec{OA}\times\vec{v_A}|=CA*v_a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

> The angular momentum is conserved given that the net force acting on the particle is parallel to the radial direction. This surely is not true for the center C
> of the elliptical orbit.

Absolutely right! The angular momentum is conserved about the center of the Earth since gravitational force is a central force. But angular momentum $L = mvr_{\perp}$ (note that it uses perpendicular distance) or $\vec{L} = m(\vec{r}\times \vec{v}).$ The perpendicular distance between the axis of revolution of the satellite (which is perpendicular to the plane of revolution) and the velocity vector of the satellite is $CA$ and $OB$, not $OA$ and $OB$.

Also, for a circular orbit, the velocity at any point is tangential to the path
(circle) itself so the radius vector will always be perpendicular to the velocity anyway.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.